# Read HBase table with where clause using Spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, hbase, hortonworks-data-platform

I am trying to read a HBase table using Spark Scala API.

**Sample Code:**

```
conf.set("hbase.master", "localhost:60000")
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "localhost")
conf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, tableName)
val hBaseRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(conf, classOf[TableInputFormat], classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable], classOf[Result])
println("Number of Records found : " + hBaseRDD.count())
```

How to add `where` clause if i use `newAPIHadoopRDD` ?

Or we need to use any `Spark Hbase Connector` to achieve this?

I saw the below Spark Hbase connector, but i don't see any example code with where clause.

https://github.com/nerdammer/spark-hbase-connector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SHC connector from HortonWorks to achieve this.

https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc

Here is a code example with Spark 2.

```
 val catalog =
        s"""{
            |"table":{"namespace":"default", "name":"my_table"},
            |"rowkey":"id",
            |"columns":{
            |"id":{"cf":"rowkey", "col":"id", "type":"string"},
            |"name":{"cf":"info", "col":"name", "type":"string"},
            |"age":{"cf":"info", "col":"age", "type":"string"}
            |}
            |}""".stripMargin

    val spark = SparkSession
        .builder()
        .appName("hbase spark")
        .getOrCreate()

    val df = spark
        .read
        .options(
            Map(
                HBaseTableCatalog.tableCatalog -> catalog
            )
        )
        .format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase")
        .load()

    df.show()
```

You can then use whatever method on your dataframe. Ex :

```
df.where(df("age") === 20)
```

Comment: I try to use it,The other fields output normally, but  cf:rowkey is not output to the target table,Is this a property of SHC?